# add share buttons above my posts without plugins

Tags: content, buttons, social-sharing

I'm trying to install share buttons above the articles of my site and I found this piece of code. Starting with, my problem is that the code is displayed at the end of the articles. I would rather have the buttons at the beginning. Would you like to help me solve the problem?

here is the code:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'br_content_with_social_buttons');
function br_content_with_social_buttons($content){
    $url = urlencode(get_permalink());
    // Get current page title
    $title = str_replace(' ', '%20', get_the_title());
    $blog_title = get_bloginfo('name');
    $content .='
    <div id="social-share">
        <strong><span>Sharing is caring</span></strong> <i class="fa fa-share-alt"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='.$url.'" target="_blank" class="facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> <span>Share</span></a>
        <a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url='.$url.'" target="_blank" class="gplus"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i> <span>+1</span></a>
        <a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text='.$title.'&amp;url='.$url.'&amp;via=YOUR_TWITTER_HANDLE_HERE" target="_blank" class="twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i> <span>Tweet</span></a>
        <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&amp;url='.$title.'" target="_blank" class="linkedin"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i> <span>Share</span></a>
        <a href="whatsapp://send?text='.$title.' '.$url.'" target="_blank" class="whatsapp"><i class="fa fa-whatsapp"></i> <span>Share</span></a>
    </div>';
    return $content;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use This Code May Help You:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'br_content_with_social_buttons');
    function br_content_with_social_buttons($content){
        $url = urlencode(get_permalink());
        // Get current page title
        $title = str_replace(' ', '%20', get_the_title());
        $blog_title = get_bloginfo('name');
        $sharebuttons ='
        <div id="social-share">
            <strong><span>Sharing is caring</span></strong> <i class="fa fa-share-alt"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='.$url.'" target="_blank" class="facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> <span>Share</span></a>
            <a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url='.$url.'" target="_blank" class="gplus"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i> <span>+1</span></a>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text='.$title.'&amp;url='.$url.'&amp;via=YOUR_TWITTER_HANDLE_HERE" target="_blank" class="twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i> <span>Tweet</span></a>
            <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&amp;url='.$title.'" target="_blank" class="linkedin"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i> <span>Share</span></a>
            <a href="whatsapp://send?text='.$title.' '.$url.'" target="_blank" class="whatsapp"><i class="fa fa-whatsapp"></i> <span>Share</span></a>
        </div>';
        return $sharebuttons.$content;
    }
```

Comment: Its great to hear you. Please Mark it right,  it will help others.